# Google Analytics show real time goal hits but not on the conversions report

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to report conversions to Google Analytics from the server side of an app after a payment is successfully processed. I'm using the Measurement Protocol from the devguides. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

The problem is that it successfully shows the goal hits on the real time conversions report, but this are not showed in the normal conversions report as goal completions.

Is there any difference between 'goal hit' and 'goal completion' I'm missing? Or is there any delay on the data that makes into the regular conversions report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delay. Per documentation it's 24-48 hours (4 hours on a 360 account), although usually the data shows up somewhat faster.

[Documentation:](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency)

> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports
>   being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and
>   metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce
>   the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day. For
>   Analytics 360 accounts, this limit is extended to 2 billion hits per
>   month.

Answer (score 1):

I used to think there was long delays in data showing up in GA reports as well, until I discovered a small bug in the GA system in regards to time zones.  The system automatically selects the date for you on the reports, but if you live in a time zone like Australia or The Philippines, these can be out of sync, and therefore, the most recent data doesn't show up.

I now always set the date to "Today" or to the last few days, and I find all data comes through within minutes, not hours.